# Dynamic upload location for Super Table within a Matrix field?

Tags: assets, matrix, plugin-supertable

I'm trying to set dynamic upload locations for my asset fields that are in a Super Table field within a Matrix field. So it's Matrix > Super Table > Asset field. I'm getting the following error when I save an entry, though. `Could not resolve the subpath “{owner.section.handle}/{owner.slug}”.`
Omitting the `owner` part doesn't work either.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried using `{owner.owner.slug}`? If you've got Matrix > Super Table > Asset, and you're trying to get an attribute on the Entry/Element, you'll need to go two level out from the Super Table field.

```
Entry
  Matrix
    Super Table
      Asset Field
```

The owner of the Super Table field is the Matrix field. The owner of the Matrix field is the Entry.

Comment: Thank you! It also works if you have a Matrix field within a Super Table field. This should be on the Craft CMS Documentation page, currently they only show: {owner.id} and they dont explain it as well as you just did. Thanks!